# AngularJS ng-bind-html not working in <ng-view> pages

Tags: angularjs

In the master page n-bind-html is working but when calling view pages any data didnt get .

ng-bind-html="home.title"  is working in the index header div.

index.html

```
             ....

             <title ng-bind-html="home.title"></title>

             ....

            <ng-view></ng-view>
```

contact.html
but ng-view contact page ng-bind-html="home.title"  not working and {{contact.info}} are not working.

```
            <h4 ng-bind-html="home.title"></h4>
            <p>{{contact.info}}</p>
```

controller:

```
    $scope.trustedHtml = function (plainText) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(plainText);
    }
    $http.get('admin/api/?s=getAbout&lang='+lang).success(
        function(r){
                $scope.about = r.text;
                //$scope.about = r.email;
        }
    );


    $http.get('admin/api/?s=getContact'+lang).success(
        function(r){
                $scope.contact = r;
                //$scope.contacttext.infoH = r[0].infoH;
                //$scope.contact.infoH = $sce.trustAsHtml(r.infoH); 

        }
    );


    $http.get('admin/api/?s=getHome&lang='+lang).success(
        function(r){
                $scope.home = r;
                $scope.home.address = $sce.trustAsHtml(r.address); 
                $scope.home.phone = $sce.trustAsHtml(r.phone); 
                $scope.home.email = $sce.trustAsHtml(r.email);
                $scope.home.title = $sce.trustAsHtml(r.title);                  
        }
    );
```

ng-view page of about is working .
about.html

```
       <div class="container" style="font-size:16px;" ng-bind-html="trustedHtml(about)"></div>
```

Comment: post controller code, routes has different scope, if home.title is in the page scope can't be visible to the route scope

Answer (score 0):

You need to add below code code for dynamically added element. [See Here](http://www.getmdl.io/started/index.html#dynamic) . Hope this helps:

```
AngularApp.run(function($rootScope, $location, $timeout) {
    $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
        $timeout(function() {
            componentHandler.upgradeAllRegistered();
        });
    });
});
```

[How Component Handle works](https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/wiki/How-the-Component-Handler-works)